# Can a Spring form command be a Map?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can a Spring form command be a Map? I made my command a Map by extending HashMap and referenced the properties using the `['property']` notation but it didn't work.

Command:

```
public class MyCommand extends HashMap<String, Object> {
}
```

HTML form:

```
Name: <form:input path="['name']" />
```

Results in the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property '[name]' of bean class [com.me.MyCommand]: Bean property '[name]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Is this not allowed or do I have incorrect syntax?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Springn MVC commands need to use JavaBeans naming conventins (ie getXXX() and setXXX()) so no you can't use a map for that.

One alternative is to have a bean with a single Map property ie:

```
public class MyCommand {
  private final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  public Map<String, Object> getProperties() { return properties; }
  // setter optional
}
```

Then you can do something like this (not 100% sure on the syntax but it is possible):

```
Name: <form:input path="properties['name']" />
```

Comment: Your sintaxis is correct, but map properties don't get actually bound. The problem is the code generated is something like <input name="propertiesName" value="valueAppearsOk"/>. So, when you submit this form, nothing puts the correct value in properties.

Comment: Map String values can be bind in JSP. Can integer values of map/object be binded?

Comment: Looks like the syntax <form:input path="properties['name']" />  works now for maps, at least in Spring 3.0.7

Answer (score 3):

Combining the answer of cletus and dbell I could actually make it work and would like to share the solution with you (including binding of values when submitting the form, a flaw reported for cletus solution)

You cannot use directly a map as command, however have another domain object that needs to wrap a lazy map

```
public class SettingsInformation {

    private Map<String, SettingsValue> settingsMap= MapUtils.lazyMap(new HashMap<String, SettingsValue>(),FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(SettingsValue.class));

    public Map<String, SettingsValue> getSettingsMap() {
        return settingsMap;
    }

    public void setSettingsMap(Map<String, SettingsValue > settingsMap) {
        this.settingsMap = settingsMap;
    }

}
```

SettingsValue is a class that actually wraps the value.

```
public class SettingsValue {

private String value;

public SettingsValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}


public SettingsValue() {

}

public String getValue() {

    return value;
}

public void setValue(String propertyValue) {

    this.value = propertyValue;
}
```

The controller method providing the model looks like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/settings", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showSettings() {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("settings");

    SettingsDTO settingsDTO = settingsService.getSettings();
    Map<String, String> settings = settingsDTO.getSettings();

    SettingsInformation settingsInformation = new SettingsInformation();

    for (Entry<String, String> settingsEntry : settings.entrySet()) {
        SettingsValue settingsValue = new SettingsValue(settingsEntry.getValue());
        settingsInformation.getSettingsMap().put(settingsEntry.getKey(), settingsValue);
    }

    modelAndView.addObject("settings", settingsInformation);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Your form should look like this

```
<form:form action="${actionUrl}" commandName="settings">
        <form:input path="settingsMap['exampleKey'].value"/>
        <input type="submit" value="<fmt:message key="settings.save"/>"/>
</form:form>
```

The controller method handling form submission works as usual

```
@RequestMapping(value="/settings", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateSettings(@ModelAttribute(value="settings") SettingsInformation settings) {
[...]
}
```

I verified the SettingsInformation bean is actually filled with the values in the form.

Thanks for helping me with this one; If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Map String values can be bind in JSP. Can integer values of map/object be binded?

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have a solution that works for me i use MapUtils.lazyMap

//My Root domain

```
    public class StandardDomain {

        private Map<String, AnotherDomainObj> templateMap= MapUtils.lazyMap(new HashMap<String, AnotherDomainObj>(),FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(AnotherDomainObj.class));

        public Map<String, AnotherDomainObj> getTemplateContentMap() {
            return templateMap;
        }

        public void setTemplateContentMap(Map<String, AnotherDomainObj > templateMap) {
            templateMap = templateMap;
        }

    }
```

//my second domain

```
public class AnotherDomainObj  {

    String propertyValue="";

        public String getPropertyValue() {
           return propertyValue;
        }

        public void setPropertyValue(String propertyValue) {
           this.propertyValue = propertyValue;
     }



}
```

//In my JSP

```
<input type="text" value="testthis" name="templateMap['keyName'].propertyValue"/>
```

Comment: Map String values can be bind in JSP. Can integer values of map/object be binded?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it can but... You need to reference it as `<form:input path="name[index].key|value"/>`

e.g.

`<form:input path="name[0].value"/>`