# Passing java.util.Map from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

I have some class named Configuration that have some fields of types java.util.List and java.util.Map.

```
public class Configuration {
    List<String> objects;
    Map<String, Integer> maps;
        // getters, setters...
}
```

I have some jsp page where user can edit this fields.

With List i have no problems, i just name my input field same as field named in class and spring converts it in @ModelAttribute.

```
<input type="text" name="objects"/>
<input type="text" name="objects"/>
<input type="text" name="objects"/>
```

With Map i have some probmels - i don't know how to name my input field for key and for value. When i'm naming them like key and value i get null in servlet.

```
<input type="text" name="key"/><input type="text" name="value"/>
```

Wnen i'm naming them like maps.key and maps.value i get empty map in servlet

```
<input type="text" name="maps.key"/><input type="text" name="maps.value"/>
```

when i'm naming them like maps i get spring converting error

```
<input type="text" name="maps"/><input type="text" name="maps"/>
```

What the correct way to pass map from jsp to servlet?

Comment: Do you mean pass the map from the servlet to jsp? The jsp gets processed after the servlet. You would normally set the map as a bean and then use a tag library to render the bean value (the Map stuff) in the jsp.

Comment: no, i mean to pass the map from jsp to servlet using form with post method and controller with post methos and @ModelAttribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't let Spring do this for you. I don't know if it can go that deep.

In your jsp, maybe you have a javascript button that adds an `<input>` field for Integers (assuming `Map<String, Integer>`) every time you want to add one. You should be able to set the name attribute of this field and always use some specific prefix. For example, use the prefix `NUMBER_OF_`. Then a field would become, eg., `NUMBER_OF_players`, where `players` is a value you provided. So the input would look like:

```
<input type="text" name="NUMBER_OF_players" />
```

In your controller, pass the `HttpServletRequest` to your handler method and call [`getParameterMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29)

```
Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
for (String key: parameterMap.keySet()) {
    if (key.startsWith("NUMBER_OF_")) {
        parameterKeyList.add(key); // add it to a list of parameters that are going to be
                                   // used for your Configuration instance
                                   // you know this is a good one because it has the prefix
    }
}

Map<String, Integer> maps = ...;

for (String parameter : parameterKeyList) {
    String value = request.getParameter(parameter); 
    Integer integer = Integer.parseInt(value);
    maps.put(parameter, integer);
}

Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setMaps(maps);
```

I've not added all the `null` checks and exception handling, I leave that to you.

You could possibly let Spring generate part of the `Configuration` instance (the fields that are known), then do the rest yourself with the above.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I also thought about this decision but still i hope that there is an easy-way solution using spring.

Comment: @Xenobyte Spring uses your bean field names to map request parameters. Since this is a map, there's nothing telling it which parameters to get (use a keys). What Spring might let you do is register a custom binder, but the logic within it will be something like the above.

Comment: @Xenobyte Or maybe you can, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736186/can-a-spring-form-command-be-a-map

Answer (score 0):

you can use spring:bind tag to help you check this [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/tag/BindTag.html) and this [link](http://mattfleming.com/node/134?page=1)