# JSP to hashmap?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, hashmap

I have a dynamic HTML form built from a list :

```xml
<form action="<c:url value="/categorize" />" method="POST">
    <table>
        <c:forEach items="${listes}" var="liste">
            <tr>
                <td><label for="${liste }">Does your list <strong>${liste}</strong>
                        corresponds to one of these categories ?
                </label></td>
                <td><select id="${liste}">
                        <option value="None" selected>None</option>
                        <option value="Family">Family</option>
                        <option value="Professionnal">Professionnal</option>
                        <option value="Friend">Friend</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Categorize</button>
</form>
```

As you can see, I have multiple elements in my form, each with an associated value. I would like to use this information in a controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="categorize)
public void categorize(@RequestParam("myCuteHashMap") HashMap<K,L> hm){
    // do things
}
```

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Use JSON , it will be easier ! Or you can map it to a command class .

Comment: @TheNewIdiot how JSON would help in this case? Note: I'm curious about this approach :)

Comment: IMO, this does not make sense. Your business logic should work on the keys (select values) and not their description (this is just metadata).

Comment: That's what I'm trying todo. However, I can't see how to transmit these keys since they are generated dynamically.
@TheNewIdiot I don't know JSON so if I can avoid using it, it'll save me time :p

Comment: @fxm: the key is the options' value (`value="None"`). The browser submits this after submitting the form, so that you do not receive a map. Instead it's just one value (e.g. `None`). Try firebug or Chrome's developer mode to track the request.

Comment: @home I'm not sure to understand. You mean there is a difference between datas printed by the browser in a GET request (for instance, here, ?${liste}=None ) is different than the one sent to the server ? If so, have you an idea an the procedure I should follow to use the datas sent ?

Comment: @fxm: the browser does send form data to the server. In case of a `select.option` tag it is the value defined in the `value` tag (or the tag inside the `options` tag in case `value` is not defined... as I said, try to monitor the request using browser features.

Comment: Well, I found the answer in [this post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736186/can-a-spring-form-command-be-a-map